# Selecting all from one table and joining to another

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables, a manufacturer table with a primary of ManufacturerID and an atrribute of Manufacturer_Name, then iv'e got a product table with a primary of ProductID, a few attributes and the ManufacturerID foreign key. I want to be able to display the manufacturer name before the product name with all the other product attributes there after on my output page but I cant get the join working, so far I have this query for the join:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM product 
            LEFT JOIN Manufacturer_Name 
            ON product.ProductID = manufacturer.ManufacturerID 
            WHERE Product_Name 
            LIKE '%$searchq%' ";
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN Manufacturer_Name ??

Comment: I think it should be LEFT JOIN Manufacturer

Comment: Like i said, i am completely new and just trying to get started/understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table name should be there with JOIN, also ManufacturerID will be the JOIN key. So the query will be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM product. 
            LEFT JOIN Manufacturer manufacturer 
            ON product.ManufacturerID = manufacturer.ManufacturerID 
            WHERE product.Product_Name 
            LIKE '%$searchq%' ";
```

Comment: Please watch out for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. If `$searchq` is controlled by the user, then this is susceptible. *Always* use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).